# What is wrong here? (Attribute Error __len__)

Tags: python, tkinter

Given this relatively simple tk script:

```
import Tkinter

class buttton(Tkinter.Button):
    def __init__(self,frame,action=None):
        if action==None:
            action=self.action
        Tkinter.Button.__init__(self,frame,command=action)
        self.pack(frame)
    def action(self):
        None


root=Tkinter.Tk()
button=buttton(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When running this program, I am met with the rather cryptic error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/username/Desktop/ab.py", line 14, in <module>
    button=buttton(root)
  File "C:/Users/username/Desktop/ab.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.pack(frame)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1940, in pack_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1162, in _options
    cnf = _cnfmerge(cnf)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 114, in _cnfmerge
    for c in _flatten(cnfs):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1898, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: __len__
```

I would be more than happy for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
self.pack(frame)
```

`self.pack` doesn't take a frame argument. Remove `frame`, and it should run fine, like so:

```
self.pack()
```

Comment: That's the solution but the description is kinda vague. `pack` doesn't take a `frame` object and its help (`pack_configure(self, cnf={}, **kw)`) shows that it attempted to use `frame` as a config dictionary.

Comment: Also, it looks like in the OP's code the idea was to use `pack()` to add `self` to `frame`. That's not necessary because it's already set as a child of `frame` in the call to `Button.__init__()`.